# Cannot set redirect_url for upload through API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am uploading videos to my Vimeo account using the API and the [intridea/oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) in a Rails application.

This is how I retrieve my upload ticket:

```
require 'oauth2'
require 'json'
client = OAuth2::Client.new CLIENT_ID, SECRET, site: 'https://api.vimeo.com'
token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new client, TOKEN
response = token.post '/me/videos?redirect_url=https://foobar.com'

body = JSON.parse response.body
puts body['upload_link_secure']
```

The API endpoint I use is [documented here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/me#POST/me/videos).
The provided link in the response looks something like this:

```
https://1511635511.cloud.vimeo.com/upload?ticket_id=...&redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2Fupload%2Fapi%3F...
```

The whole process works fine, the video is uploaded, but as you can see the redirect URL was not replaced with `https://foobar.com`.
This means I won't get the `video_id` back to my app automatically.

Do you guys see what I am doing wrong?

Cheers

**SOLUTION**

As explained by [Austio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29781390/1821901) parameters for POST are send in the body, not in the url.
Also the Vimeo API requires a `type` to be set to `POST`. The follogwing snippets works now:

```
response = token.post '/me/videos', body: { type: 'POST', redirect_url: 'https://foobar.com' }
```

Or:

```
response = token.post '/me/videos' do |request|
  request.body = { type: 'POST', redirect_url: 'https://foobar.com' }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So problem then is that you are not doing a proper post format.  For posts, you will normally put the parameters in the request not in the url.  Try something like this.

```
token.post('/me/videos') do |request|
  request.params['request_url'] = "https://foobar.com"
end
```

Side note, if i am ever having trouble with an API i pull out something like postman (chrome extension) to test that the api is working as expected before troubleshooting the ruby/rails side.  You end up starting at too high of an abstraction unless you deeply understand the client you are using to post.

Comment: POST https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos is an official API endpoint (documented at https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/me#POST/me/videos). I corrected the mistake above. The problem still occurs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It pointed me in the right way. heads up though, from what I understand you have to access the body rather than the parameters.

Comment: One more question about your site note: I do use Postman, is there a similar REST client that supports OAuth2, though? That was the limiting factor here.